# How can I know if there was an error during compiling of kernel code?

Tags: linux, compilation, compiler-errors, kernel

I have compiled a custom kernel step by step from [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) link. 
The image files are created using:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-x kernel-image kernel-headers
```

After installing the images system boots to the new kernel, however, my question is that is it possible to have some errors during "make" of kernel while the images are created and the system can boot to the new kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be mistakes in the code that the compiler may or may not catch. Any hard errors, however, will cause the build to fail.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio.Do you mean after running above line the images won't be created?